# 3rd Custom "Close Reason"

Tags: discussion

Since the decision to create the custom off-topic close reasons, we've only used 2 of the 3 reason slots, so we're left with a spare custom close dialogue.

It would simplify matters if we used this for a standard dialogue warning people that the question they've asked is off-topic for the site:

e.g.

> **This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the [help center](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/help)"**

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7187/are-we-allowed-to-change-our-custom-off-topic-vtc-options

Comment: @WadCheber - Yes, there seemed to be some interest in using it (at least based on the comments) so I thought I'd make it an explicit choice. I personally would vote in favour, but I wanted to see what the community felt.

Comment: I agree, except.. our help center doesn't do a very good job of describing what is and isn't "science fiction or fantasy" :)

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - That's next on my list. That being said, we regularly see questions asked that are clearly **not** sci-fi or fantasy

Comment: Did this use to be a custom close reason and then get removed? I'm sure I've seen plenty of posts closed for this reason.

Comment: @randal'thor - before my time, but yes, this used to be a close reason. It seems to have been removed to make space for "general reference", then never reinstated.

Comment: @randal'thor This is the generic wording prepended to every off-topic description before the specific reason (or when the specific reason is a custom one), So it's so reminiscent to you because it is the exact generic wording every other off-topic closure gets put under anyway.

Comment: Hm... On Stack Overflow, you get wording largely identical to the proposed text (except "programming" instead of "science fiction or fantasy") if you choose "Other" in the close dialog.  Does that not work on SFF?

Comment: @Kevin It does, but this question is about not having to type a custom close reason in the general case.

Comment: @randal'thor that's the default close option, "Shown when no 2 off-topic reasons match on a closed question"

Answer (score 20):

**Yes, I agree.**

This dialogue should be added to the standard custom-close reasons. It seems sensible and fits in well with the site's [existing policies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm in favor of this, but the existing policies don't actually describe what science fiction/fantasy is, so I'm not sure it fits within the site's existing policies as is.

Comment: @Thunderforge - That was next on my list of "things to do"

Answer (score 2):

**No, I disagree.**

This dialogue should be used for something else, held in reserve for some other purpose, or simply not used at all.