# Review links for fourth custom close reason

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, help-center

A proposed wording for our "out of scope" close reason is being constructed at [this other meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13502/wording-for-fourth-custom-close-reason-not-about-science-fiction-or-fantasy/13503) but it needs some links to be considered ready to go.   I've simply linked to the help page [What questions can I ask about here?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but some of you may know of some meta articles to link to for even more in-depth detail. Or this may be all we need.  The wording was started by Skooba and is now a community wiki, so you can edit it yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure we need a 4th reason at this point. It's fairly clear that our mods don't care and a quick look at the custom closes over the last few weeks and months would suggest that the community has just recreated it on their own.

Comment: Additionally the reason for rejecting the original wording is, in my very humble opinion, silly.

Comment: FWIW links aren't needed per se though some links would certainly be better. However, having placeholders, like before your edit, with just _[Meta Link 1]_ would mean the CMs won't implement the reason.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot  Just trying to move things forward.  I guess any more detailed information could just be edited in to the help article.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot  FWIW future works isn't in the "what should I avoid asking about" article yet.

Comment: @Spencer mods can't edit most help pages, including that one :/

Answer (score 3):

Nearly two years on from the initial discussion and we still don't have our third 'custom close' reason.

Not to fret though, because out of the last 55 questions that were closed '[with community-specific reasons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days)', a huge proportion of them (more than 80%) were closed with the reason...

> *This question does not appear to be about Science Fiction or Fantasy, as defined in the [FAQ] and Help Centre*

...or some variation thereof.

**So it seems that we don't need to bother creating a new custom reason since the community has just gone ahead and done it all on its own.**

---

[image]

Comment: Well, implementing a custom close reason would save people from having to type that out, and make the wording consistent.

Comment: @Spencer - I use the [AutoReviewComment plugin](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments). It means that I can type a phrase once and then replicate it at will

Comment: "No longer maintained by the author" doesn't give me a lot of confidence.

Comment: I like seeing my unique snowflakes of close reasons in your list :D

Comment: @AndresF. - Mine are all very boringly similar.

Comment: The reason "*not about Science Fiction or Fantasy, as defined in the FAQ and Help Center*" seems problematic. As far as I can tell, the FAQ (now called "Site Tour") and the Help Center do not indicate which types of works are on-topic or off-topic.

Comment: @galacticninja - This is the relevant page : https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic